# Rails 4 has many through with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to set up a standard relationship as following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :post_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories
  attr_accessor :category_ids
end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to post
  belongs_to category
end
```

I am using ActiveAdmin and need to set up checkboxes to describe the relationship. 
I have tried many different ways to have the checkboxes save. Here is my admin post.rb file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  permit_params :content, category_ids: []

  form do |f|
    f.inputs # Include the default inputs
    f.inputs "Categories" do
      f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: Category.all
    end
    f.actions # Include the default actions
  end
end
```

I have tried different permit params such as

```
permit_params :content, :categories
permit_params :content, post_categories_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :category_id]
permit_params :content, category_ids: [:id]
```

The database is set up as shown in the rails tutorial, and the relationship seems to work elsewhere except for being saved from activeadmin. I even tried to use `param.permit!` to permit all params, but still no luck.

I have found many posts of seemingly the same question, but many give different answers and nothing seems to work.

What is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24486212/3199803 This solution worked, but it seems like there should be a more concise way.
The other solutions for the same question do not work for me.

Comment: What's in the log file at the point when the create action is started?

Answer (score 2):

Little late but this question is googled first for me, so I assume it can be helpful to other "googlers"

```
#models/post.rb

accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories#, allow_destroy: true
```

---

```
#AA Post conf file

permit_params :content, category_ids: []
```